# Updating nested arrays with Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.1

First sorry, i am only developing in php for a month and i do not know how to update this with laravel

I would like to update multiple photos.

Photos have a title description, etc.

My problem is i have no clue how to do it.

I tried the following

```
public function update(Request $request, Photo $photo)
{
    // loop through array of id's
    foreach ($request->photo_id as $id)
    {
        // find 
        $photos = $photo->find($id);
        // loop throug input fields
        foreach ($request->except('_token', 'tags', 'photo_id') as $key => $value)
        {
            $photos->$key = $value;
            $photos->save();
        }
    }
    die();
}
```

I get the following error

```
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
```

So i figured out the problem is with the value

And the results are like this

Key variable

```
string(5) "title"
string(10) "country_id"
string(7) "city_id"
string(11) "category_id"
string(9) "cruise_id"
string(12) "itinerary_id"
string(4) "desc"
string(6) "people"
string(5) "title"
string(10) "country_id"
string(7) "city_id"
string(11) "category_id"
string(9) "cruise_id"
string(12) "itinerary_id"
string(4) "desc"
string(6) "people"
```

Value variable results

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "title one"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "title two"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

I tried several other attempts but nothing works

Could please someone help me out with this?

Comment: Show your `routes.php` and a form which makes a request to `update` action.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about what is passing you the request object, I can't really go into specifics but you probably want to get your request object to look something like this:

```
'photos' => [
    {
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'title one',
        // more properties ....
    },
    {
        'id' => 2,
        'title' => 'title two',
        // more properties ....
    },
]
```

Then try something like this:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    // Loop through the request photo id's
    $request->photos->each(function($photo) use ($request) {
       // Return the photo object you want to update
       $photo = Photo::find($photo->id);

       // Get the things you want from the request and update the object
       $photo->title= $request[$photo_id]->title;

       // Save the object
       $photo->save();
    })
}
```

You also may want to try out the `dd();` function instead of `die();`. It makes debugging a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think, Photo Model missed the fillable array.

```
protected $fillable = ['var1', 'var2', ...];
```